# Biological Process with UV Light Product

Tags: biology, creature-design

I have bacteria that will serve as the basis of the ecosystem providing UV light for plants within the enclosed, underground ecosystem. What sort of biological process could allow these bacteria to produce UV light in quantities needed.

Comment: how big is space? Exactly how much UV light is needed?

Comment: Q1:  why do plants need UV light?